# Connecting Android app to Java server via JSON

Tags: java, android, json, http

I am creating an android app which stores data such as "name" "latitude" "longitude" in a MSSQL database.

I am planning to connect the android app to a server which then connects to a mssql database server.

I have established the Java -> MSSQL connection fine and can read/write data with no problems.

Now I want to be able to send / receive these objects between the java server and the android app.

I created 'file.json' and stored it on a web server containing:

```
{"name":"shopname","address":"123 fake street","type":"unknown", "notes":"service is really good."}
```

and I am able to pull this data back into an object with no trouble.

My question is:

How do I get the java server to serve this data to my android app?  I want to be able to use:

```
URL objectGet = new URL("http://10.0.1.8/file.json");
    URLConnection yc = objectGet.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
            yc.getInputStream()));
```

and then

```
DataObject objs = gson.fromJson(in, DataObject.class);
```

What would be the best way of setting this up?

Comment: Do you have an app server (i.e. tomcat or other) you can run your Java/MSSQL bridge on as a servlet? _If not_ - is the data somewhat static - i.e. is it acceptable behavior to regenerate the json at regular intervals?

Comment: No, I have not setup a tomcat or other server.  I was planning to just use a java application.
The data is not static at all.  It changes based on GPS coordinates from the android handset.
But I was planning to just regenerate the json at regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

please refer my answer on this post. [Why null value returns in json parsing in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293331/why-null-value-returns-in-json-parsing-in-android/11293894#11293894)

This may help you. The best way would be:

- Connect to the server using read() function and fetch the JSON string from server
- parse the read data to your object instance using GSON fromJson function

Comment: Thanks for the reply

I'm find with using GSON to parse the JSON data back into the objects.  I'm trying to figure out the server side.

How do I get a java server to generate the JSON data and have it available at http://javaserver.example.com/file.json ?

How do I send data up from the android server (Name, Latitude, Longitude) ?

I'm starting to think perhaps I'll be better off using PHP as a middle tier as it seems easier to set up.

Comment: so this is a J2EE question. anyway you create a java servlet and make a necessary JSON string inside the doGet/doPost methods and write this JSON string to the writer object of the response. refer this link for making such a [servlet](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/json/json-servlet-example.shtml). also set the contenttype to `application/json` using `response.setContentType("application/json");`

Answer (score 0):

To test your app you can host the service via IIS or Apache on your development machine and then hit your server via

```
http://10.0.2.2/file.json
```

10.0.2.2 is the special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e., 127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

See:  [Emulator Network Address Space](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses) in the official docs